# Python 'else' and 'if not' statement in a for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, if-statement

```
databasepath='/Users/software/database.txt'
sinfo=[]
soi = pnevli[1].header['OBJECT']
with open(databasepath) as fp:
   for line in fp:
       if soi in line:
           line_array = line.split(sep=None, maxsplit=-1)
           sinfo.append(line_array)
           sinfo = np.array(sinfo)[0]
           source = {
            'Name': sinfo[1],
            'PSR': sinfo[2],
            'RA': sinfo[3],
            'DEC': sinfo[5],
            'RAJD': sinfo[11],
            'DECJD': sinfo[13]
           }
           print(source)
           savepath = obspath/obsid
           file1 = open(str(savepath)+'/'+'PSR_'+soi+'.txt',"w")
           file1.write(str(source))
           file1.close()
       #if not soi in line:
           #print('The source is not listed')
```

I have written the above code in which it reads a header in a fits file and compares it to a database (**database.txt**) and if it finds a match, it copies the entire row of that database and writes it in a new text file. I have two problems here:

**First problem:** Lets say, the database has 1000 rows and it finds a match, if I use **"if not soi in line:"** or **"else:"**, it will copy of the matched row to a text file and then prints 999 times `The source is not listed` because it is in a for a loop. What I actually want is to write this statement (once) only if there is no match!

**Second problem:** When it writes the row in the text file, I would like it to write each string in a new line (for instance *'Name': sinfo[1]* first line, *'PSR': sinfo[2]* second line and so on, but I don't know how exactly to insert \n so it could jumpy to a new line!

Comment: Can you give a sample of your input text file?

Comment: Sure here a line from the input, 8     J0024-7204ab J0024-7204ab 00:24:08.1 5.0e-04 -72:04:47.6 2.0e-03     4.200 6.0e-01    -2.900 5.0e-01      6.03400625 2.1e-06    -72.07988944 5.6e-07  0.003705 6.0e-16 9.82e-21 9.0e-24      24.37 2.0e-02     2.54 5.98e+09  1.93e+08 7.62e+33

Answer (score 1):

So I can't really test this but here's a quick example of what you could do.

For your first problem, use a `defaultdict` to create a collection of your data and just check if it's empty or not at the end. The value of using a `defaultdict` is we can just start appending to each key without checking if there is a key yet.
Example:

```
# defaultdict
sources['Name'].append(line_array[1])

# regular dict
if 'Name' in sources:
    sources['Name'].append(line_array[1])
else:
    sources['Name'] = [line_array[1]]
```

We can also wait to write to our file till all of our data is parsed.

```
from collections import defaultdict

databasepath = '/Users/software/database.txt'

sources = defaultdict(list)

soi = pnevli[1].header['OBJECT']

with open(databasepath) as fp:
    for line in fp:
        if soi in line:
            line_array = line.split(sep=None, maxsplit=-1)
            sources['Name'].append(line_array[1])
            sources['PSR'].append(line_array[2])
            sources['RA'].append(line_array[3])
            sources['DEC'].append(line_array[5])
            sources['RAJD'].append(line_array[11])
            sources['DECJD'].append(line_array[13])

if sources:
    # this doesn't look quite right
    # im guessing it should be
    # savepath = f'{obspath}/{obsid}'
    savepath = obspath/obsid
    with open(f'{savepath}/PSR_{soi}.txt', "w") as file1:
        # this basically just says
        # for each element in our list of names
        # for each key in our dictionary
        # write   the key : the value of the current index
        # so for your given example it would print
        # Name: '<value of first name>'
        # PSR: '<value of first PSR>'
        # etc..
        for i in range(len(sources['Name'])):
            for key in sources:
                file1.write(f"{key}: {sources[key][i]}\n")
else:
    print('The source is not listed')
```

For comparison reasons. here is a version using a regular dict.

```
databasepath = '/Users/software/database.txt'

sources = {'Name': [],
           'PSR': [],
           'RA': [],
           'DEC': [],
           'RAJD': [],
           'DECJD': []
          }


soi = pnevli[1].header['OBJECT']

with open(databasepath) as fp:
    for line in fp:
        if soi in line:
            line_array = line.split(sep=None, maxsplit=-1)
            sources['Name'].append(line_array[1])
            sources['PSR'].append(line_array[2])
            sources['RA'].append(line_array[3])
            sources['DEC'].append(line_array[5])
            sources['RAJD'].append(line_array[11])
            sources['DECJD'].append(line_array[13])

if sources['Name']:
    savepath = obspath/obsid
    with open(f'{savepath}/PSR_{soi}.txt', "w") as file1:
        for i in range(len(sources['Name'])):
            for key in sources:
                file1.write(f"{key}: {sources[key][i]}\n")
else:
    print('The source is not listed')
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. It works. Just a quick question, since I do a lot of data collection printing/writing, is defaultdict is superior compare to create a list as I did or normal dictionary creation? I am coming from IDL programming language where it is very easy to create a structure (https://www.harrisgeospatial.com/docs/CREATE_STRUCT.html) and fill it with your desired method so I am trying to find a good replacement in python for these kinds of stuff.

Comment: In python, regular `dict`s will raise a `KeyError` if you try to reference them without assigning something to said Key. So for example, if you want a 'Name' key's value to be a list of names you could just initialize it with an empty list like so: `my_dict = {'Name': []}`. The reason I don't like that is 1. you have a long initialization line and 2. `if sources:` looks a little better than `if sources['Name']:`. I'll add an example to my answer using a normal `dict`.

Comment: All a `defaultdict` does is when it sees `sources['Name'].append(line_array[1])` for the first time is say "'Name' key hasn't been referenced yet. What is my default?" Then it sees  that it should default to an empty `list` and sets it that before appending.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you code works fine apart from the mentioned issues, below is the solution.

Problem 1 : To print "not found" once. Bring the print statement outside of loop and can use a flag variable.

Problem 2 : To add a new line into your text file, write `\n` alont with you line.

Try this :

```
databasepath='/Users/software/database.txt'
sinfo=[]
soi = pnevli[1].header['OBJECT']

found = False
with open(databasepath) as fp:
   for line in fp:
       if soi in line:
           line_array = line.split(sep=None, maxsplit=-1)
           sinfo.append(line_array)
           sinfo = np.array(sinfo)[0]
           source = {
            'Name': sinfo[1],
            'PSR': sinfo[2],
            'RA': sinfo[3],
            'DEC': sinfo[5],
            'RAJD': sinfo[11],
            'DECJD': sinfo[13]
           }
           print(source)
           savepath = obspath/obsid
           file1 = open(str(savepath)+'/'+'PSR_'+soi+'.txt',"w")
           file1.write(str(source) + "\n")
           file1.close()

           found = True

   if not found:
       print('The source is not listed')
```

Comment: Please let me know incase I am wrong or you need any clarification or have any queries.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. for the first problem. where the name is not in the database instead of printing the statement, it gives an error: NameError: name 'found' is not defined and for the second problem. it still writes everything in a single line